# Magento 2: Mass 301 Redirects for 404 Pages

Tags: magento2, extensions, 301-redirect

I have a need in magento2 in Extension create like magento1 Mass / Bulk Redirects (301, 302, or any status) for Magento 404 Pages.

Comment: so you are wanting all of your redirects to be a 404?

Comment: yes . I want that's.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach this.

From the admin panel click on the Marketing module. Under SEO & Search click on the URL rewrite. From there create a custom URL rewrite for the links that you want. It is simple and should solve the request. Please let us know how this works for you.

Comment: I have the need in my custom module..not admin setting.You can refer this URL: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162415/check-action-noroute-404-on-every-page-using-observer-not-working-magento-2/162424?noredirect=1#comment223535_162424