# Check action noRoute (404) on Every page using Observer not working Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, routing

How to check action `noRoute` (404) on every page using Observer?

*etc/events.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
      <observer name="my_observer" instance="Module\Path\To\MyClass" shared="false" />
  </event>
</config>
```

created observer class.

```
<?php 

namespace Module\Namespace\Path;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class MyClass implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
       $request = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest();
        $actionName = $request->getActionName();
       echo $actionName; // 404 page not gettig "noRoute"
   }

}
```

Comment: You want to track the 404 not found page?

Comment: yes.I want getActionName() while 404..in magento1 get "noRoute" but in magento2 not this.

Comment: AFAIK, If using rewrite url, you cannot get the module.

Comment: ok but getActionName(); method give me 'index' in 404..

Answer (score 4):

I have added a custom no route handler using the following code

```
<?xml version="0.1"?>
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="handlerClassesList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="hello" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Smartie\HelloRouter\App\Router\NoRouteHandler</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create NoRouteHandler.Php

```
<?php

namespace Smartie\HelloRouter\App\Router;

class NoRouteHandler implements \Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerInterface
{
    public function process(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $this->_response->setRedirect('http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions', 301);
        $this->_response->sendResponse();
    }
}
```

It's Worked..but some of the category and products pages not find action of modules.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Forgot Observer, should use Plugin as well as possible. Because, your observer will be called each time when making a request. So, it it not good for performance.</del>

If we want to **track the 404 not found page only**, you should follow below way.

On the front page, the "noRoute" will use the controller: `vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Noroute/Index.php`

We should use Plugin:

For example:

*app/code/Vendor/NoRoute/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index">
        <plugin name="trackNoRoutePages"
                type="Vendor\NoRoute\Controller\Plugin\TrackNoRoutePages"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Your Plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\NoRoute\Controller\Plugin;

class TrackNoRoutePages
{
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index $subject,
        $return
    ) {

       //Your code here
        return $return;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** If category and product are using url rewrite, seem that we cannot get the module name

Comment: Ok..that's Right answer..but I need in Observer..above my answer also worked for me.

Comment: @Magento2Devloper forgot Observer, should use Plugin. Because, your observer will be called each time when making a request. So, it it not good for performance.

Comment: ok Thanx i will check it.

Comment: @Magento2Devloper yeah! check it and let me know.

Comment: Thanx.but it didn't work for me I need category and products pages also..any idea about it?

Comment: AFAIK, If using rewrite url, you cannot get the module.

Comment: yes.Thanx for giving your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try event `controller_action_predispatch_cms_noroute_index`.
It will call only for 404 pages.